# Reading CsvReader field text field into Boolean field?

Tags: c#, boolean, csvreader

I am new to using `CsvReader` and it is going well.

My object currently has these fields:

```
public class CLMExplorerStudent
{
    [Name("Student ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Name("Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Name("First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Name("Gender")]
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [Name("Active")]
    public string Active { get; set; }

    [Name("Role")]
    public string Role { get; set; }

    [Name("Use For")]
    public string UseFor { get; set; }

    [Name("Use Where")]
    public string UseWhere { get; set; }

    [Name("Email Address")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Name("Phone #")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [Name("Remarks")]
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
}
```

The `Active` field has a value in the CSV file of `Y` or `N`. Is it possible to map this so that the property in my class can be a `bool` property?

I am using the standard method for reading the CSV file:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(strPath))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    var records = csv.GetRecords<CLMExplorerStudent>();
}
```

I obviously know that I can simply test the value against `Y` or `N` instead but I would prefer to read into a `bool` property.

I only need to read in from the CSV file and not write out to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding custom field attributes to CsvHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59459629/adding-custom-field-attributes-to-csvhelper)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen So I have to use a **convertor** or some kind to map to `bool`?

Comment: Exactly! I posted an example below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement a custom type converter and register it using the `[TypeConverter]` attribute:

```
using CsvHelper.Configuration;
using CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes;
using CsvHelper.TypeConversion;

class YesNoConverter : DefaultTypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
        => "YES".StartsWith(text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    

    public override string ConvertToString(object value, IWriterRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
        => value is bool b && b ? "Y" : "N";
}

public class CLMExplorerStudent
{
    // ...

    [Name("Active")]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(YesNoConverter))]
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I would be right in saying that `string Active` needs to be changed to `bool Active` in your code?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Correct!

Comment: See my answer just added.

Answer (score 1):

I also found this page: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/attributes/

Where it suggests:

```
[BooleanTrueValues("yes")]
[BooleanFalseValues("no")]
public bool IsBool { get; set; }
```

So:

```
[BooleanTrueValues("Y")]
[BooleanFalseValues("N")]
public bool Active{ get; set; }
```